# updating (override) and displaying an arrays from function

Tags: c++

So I am working on the "life game", and I am trying to display my results from `currentGen` then over ride those results and display them in place of the last results. For example:

```
00000
00000
00000
```

will be replaced with

```
00100
00100
00100
```

each time a new result needs to be shown it replaces the old results. My problem is the results just display one after the other like this

```
00000
00000
00000
00100
00100
00100
00000
01110
00000
```

I tried using this to display the results of the `currentGen` array, but it just outputs all `0`. Also here is a link to all code I am working with. http://ideone.com/QG4tsS

```
   for (int i=0;i<XXX;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<YYY;j++) {
                currentGen[i][j] += currentGen[i][j];
                cout << currentGen[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: There is no portable way to clear a screen, or to go back a few lines in the output, to over write prior output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working under **Windows**, calling `system("cls")` before your output, should do what you need. If you're using **Linux**, calling `system("clear")` works.

Note that in order to use those functions, you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` (or `<iostream>` under most Windows IDE's).

Answer (score 0):

A tricky method is use more than 25 NewLine(endl) to clear screen manually, before you print your data.

Comment: People can set a different size of the command line (in lines), and then this method won't work.